# JavaFx TreeView Search on keyevent

Tags: javafx-2

I am having a JavaFx tree view and i need to search items starting with a string, this string is taken every time user presses a key.
Search and traverse the tree on key pressing.
Please elaborate with an example.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the relevant bits from your code so we can elaborate from that.